# IFrame with facebook tabs

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

I want to get iframe application but on top of it, would love to put tabs.  and iframe are not really seem compatible. Do you guys know any work around this?

Thanks,
Ebe

Comment: @ebeworld, please provide more information so users could more easily help u out.

Comment: Okay, after thinking for a couple of moments, I'll ask the following: **1:** what are you trying to do? **2:** how are you trying to do it? **3:** What have you tried so far? **4:** What errors did you experience?

Comment: @ricebowl, you didnt even think couple of moments before answering? LOL. Well i was developing a facebook app though Iframe options and some tags are forbidden in certain block level elements due to XSS, and facebook solves it through common xd_reciever. But still, cant embed iframe in facebook tabs. Wonder if someone already solved this...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an iframe in a Facebook Tab application due to restrictions from Facebook, though in [this blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/402) from mid-August they say they will begin supporting IFrames for Page tabs "in the next few months".

There are other restrictions for applications which live within a Tab too, eg you have to use FBJS methods instead of regular javascript. It's a pain in the neck.

In [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/alisamleo/fb-pages-transition-jan2010), from January, Facebook suggest that if you really need iframe functionality in a Tab you can work around it by not putting your application in the Tab... make a Tab containing just a link to a Canvas Page, where your application can use iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you are talking about a 'tab-style' UI for your application then it is possible with using iframes. Just use javascript to show and hide different content divs.

Here is an example of an app with a tab-style UI (and it's a Tab app, so it can't use iframes):
http://www.facebook.com/VansEurope?v=app_122643704452302